# LINQ or Lambda for two foreach query

Tags: c#, linq, file-system

I have a Document Name Table in my SQL database and Files in the Content folder.
I have two lists: `ListOfFileNamesSavedInTheDB` and `ListOfFileNamesInTheFolder`.

Basically, I am getting all file names saved in the Database and checking if it exists in the Folder, and if not, delete the file name from the database.

```
 var clientDocList = documentRepository.Documents.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientID).ToList();

 if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
                bool fileNotExist = false;
                foreach (var file in fileList)
                {
                    foreach(var clientDoc in clientDocList)
                    {
                        if (clientDoc.DocFileName.Trim().ToUpper()==file.ToUpper().Trim())
                        {
                            fileNotExist = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (fileNotExist)
                    {
                        //Delete file name from Database
                    }
                }
            }
```

The code I have written works fine, this inquiry being purely for educational purposes. I want to know how others would do this better and cleaner. I especially hate the way I use two `for` loops to get data. There has to be a more efficient way.

Comment: The title of your question is misleading because the code that is necessary to delete something isn't posted. This means that your question lacks context, consequently I vote-to-close it. Please post the complete method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I'd suggest is make the 2 lists the same type(string).  Now the file list can be an exclusion list that contains only the filenames that aren't in the database.  Something like this should work:

```
    var clientDocList = documentRepository
        .Documents
        .Where(c => c.ClientID == clientID)
        .Select(d => d.DocFileName
        .Trim()
        .ToUpper()).ToList();

    var fileExclusionList = Directory
        .GetFiles(directoryPath)
        .Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)
        .Trim()
        .ToUpper())
        .Except(clientDocList).ToArray();
```

Comment: This code would be easier to understand if it were split into several lines.

Comment: Thank you for your help Tinstaafl, but it is not working. is says  'Path.GetFileName(string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context. I tried this      var fileExclusionList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath).Select(Path.GetFileName).Except(clientDocList).ToArray();  But it says IEnumerable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload

Comment: @AliAzra -  It looks to me the problem is with using `Path.GetFileName` without passing in a string.  My original code just copied yours and I didn't see that bug.  I've corrected my code.

Comment: @RolandIllig - done.

Comment: Thank you Tinstaffl, I really appreciate all your help but still, I am having the same problem. Query return type is  IEnumerable<string>' and  Except(clientDocList) is not defined with IEnumerable. I used ToList() and it worked.

Comment: @AliAzra - I think you're using older version of the library.  In the newest version IEnumerable<string> does have Except extension method.